# If statement SyntaxError: invalid syntax?

Tags: python, syntax

I am trying to run a simple program but I can't seem to get over this syntax error.

```
try:
    grade = float(raw_input("Enter a score between 0.0 and 1.0:\n"))
    if grade < 0 or grade > 1
        print ("That is not between 0.0 or 1.0")
    elif grade >= .9
        print ("A")
    elif grade >= .8 and grade < .9
        print ("B")
    elif grade >= .7 and grade < .8
        print ("C")
    elif grade >= .6 and grade < .7
        print ("D")
    else grade < .6
        print ("F")

except:
    print ("Enter a numeric value!")
```

The error I get is line 3, if grade < 0 or grade > 1: SyntaxError: invalid syntax.

Comment: You need a colon after the if and else statements.  `if grade < 0 or grade > 1:`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if`, `elif`, and `else` statements (along with a few others) in Python require a colon at the end of the line. For example:

```
if grade < 0 or grade > 1:
```

Also, `else` is a catch-all and thus does not use a condition.

```
else:
```

Comment: Thanks Tigerhawk, I'll keep that in mind moving forward!!! However, now I'm getting an error on line 13 on the else statement even after i added the colon... Could you advise?

Comment: @HotChile - At that point in the code, `grade` _must_ be less than 0.6. You could check for it explicitly (and redundantly) with `elif grade < 0.6`, or use an `else` statement. The `else` statement doesn't take a condition. Please see [the relevant section in the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements).

Comment: I see what you mean, I'll just make it an else statement w/out a condition. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Note the syntax for if, else if(elif) and else statements

```
try:
    grade = float(raw_input("Enter a score between 0.0 and 1.0:\n"))
    if grade < 0 or grade > 1:
        print ("That is not between 0.0 or 1.0")
    elif grade >= .9:
        print ("A")
    elif grade >= .8 and grade < .9:
        print ("B")
    elif grade >= .7 and grade < .8:
        print ("C")
    elif grade >= .6 and grade < .7:
        print ("D")
    else:
        print ("F")

except:
    print ("Enter a numeric value!")
```

Comment: Line 13, or the else statement is still giving me a syntax error : Invalid syntax.... Help?

Comment: @HotChile Sorry please check the updated answer. Else catches everything outside the previously defined conditions.